# 2 ListAdapter and more, in one Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

How I can add 2 `ListAdapter` and more, in one Activity? For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For each listview I would do this

```
final String1[] menu1 = {"menu","menu","menu"};
final String2[] menu2 = {"menu","menu","menu"};
final String3[] menu3 = {"menu","menu","menu"};
ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
ListView lv3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu1));
lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu1));
lv3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu1));
```

Comment: Sorry, tell me please, what I must write in listView1.xml? I have little experience in xml layout.

Comment: That depends on everything you're trying to accomplish.  Since I'm guessing you're pretty new, check out http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6 They go over a lot of stuff

Comment: I solved something like this:
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView02"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>